# Refer to other jade file in Node JS

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I started working with `node.js` and `express`. Now I want to add a link which refers to another jade file (Open a new site).
My folder structure is the following:

```
test/app.js

test/views/index.jade

test/views/games.jade
```

My target is to refer with a link inside the index.jade to the games.jade.
The index works perfect but if I try to refer to games.jade, I get the following error:

```
Cannot GET /games.jade
```

Here's a little part of my app.js

```
app.get('/', function (req, res){
res.render('index');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('games.jade');
});
```

Inside the index.jade, I try to refer with the following line:

```
a(href="games.jade") Games
```

So how do I fix this issue? I think there is a routing problem but I can't find the solution.
I also checked this question but there wasn't any success:
[Linking to other jade files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130215/linking-to-other-jade-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to register that route with your apps router for the route `/games`

Then use the route like so.

```javascript
app.get('/', function (req, res){
   res.render('index');
});

app.get('/games', function(req, res){
   res.render('games.jade');
});
```

the route or link will then be `(href="/games") Games`

Comment: Worked perfect! Thx!
Just btw, you forgot the a in front of (href="/games") Games
So it's a (href="/games") Games

Answer (score 1):

That's wrong you can't have two equal routes `app.get('/')` do a new one like:

```
app.get('/games', function(req, res){
  res.render('games.jade');
});
```

And then link that like this:

```
a(href="/games") Games
```